# Perturbation Theory Ambiguity?

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory, semi-riemannian-geometry, special-relativity

I am trying to solve problem 2.1 in Schwartz, which is to derive the transformations $x \rightarrow \frac{x+vt}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$ and $t \rightarrow \frac{t+vx}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$ in perturbation theory. Start with Galilean transformation $x \rightarrow x + v_gt$. Add a transformation $t \rightarrow t + \delta t$ and solve for $\delta t$ assuming it is linear in $x$ and $t$ and preserves $t^2 - x^2$ to $O(v^2)$ with $v_g = v$. Repeat for $\delta t$ and $\delta x$ to second order in $v$ and show that the result agrees with the second-order expansion of the full transformations for some function $v(v_g)$.

Could someone explain to me what "...for some function $v(v_g)$ means?"

Expanding $x$ and $t$ as perturbative series in $v$:

$$x' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} v^n (a_nx+b_nt)$$
$$t' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} v^n (c_nx+d_nt)$$

Where $a_0 = 1$, $b_0 = 0$, $c_0 = 0$, $d_0 = 1$, $b_1 = 1$ to conform with Galilean transformation.

Requiring Lorentz invariance (*):

$$x'^2 - t'^2 = \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty} v^{n+m} \bigg((a_nx+b_nt)(a_mx+b_mt)-(c_nx+d_nt)(c_mx+d_mt) \bigg)=x^2-t^2$$

Order $O(v^0)$:
$$(a_0x+b_0t)^2-(c_0x+d_0t)^2 = x^2 - t^2$$
$$(a_0^2-c_0^2)x^2+2(a_0b_0-c_0d_0)xt+(b_0^2-d_0^2)t^2=x^2-t^2$$
which is consistent with the required $0$ order terms above.

Order $O(v^1)$:
$$(a_0x+b_0t)(a_1x+b_1t)-(c_0x+d_0t)(c_1x+d_1t)=0$$
$$x(a_1x+b_1t)-t(c_1x+d_1t)=0$$
which gives $a_1 = d_1 = 0$ and using $b_1 = 1$ we find $c_1 = 1$

Order $O(v^2)$:
$$2x(a_2x+b_2t)-2t(c_2x+d_2t)+t^2-x^2=0$$
$$(2a_2-1)x^2+(1-2d_2)t^2+2(b_2-c_2)xt=0$$

Now $a_2 = d_2 = \frac{1}{2}$, and here is where the trouble is $b_2 = c_2$, which is completely undetermined.

Order $O(v^3)$:
$$x(a_3x+b_3t)-t(c_3c+d_3t)+t(a_2x+b_2t)-x(c_2x+d_2t)=0$$
$$x^2(a_3-c_2)+xt(b_3-c_3+a_2-d_2)+t^2(-d_3+b_2)=0$$
and now the rest of the series depends on the $b_2$ term, which is undetermined.

Why doesn't Lorentz invariance uniquely fix all the coefficient terms, despite the fact that we are considering $SO(1,1)$, with an assumed origin (so no translations allowed)? Is this a mathematical artefact of perturbative series?

Comment: I don't see the $v(v_g)$ in [Schwartz's book (google book link)](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=HbdEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=schwartz+derive+lorentz+transformation+perturbation+theory&source=bl&ots=mTkyat01up&sig=ACfU3U2CjhXR1IYUphYijScJCOpe9RtepA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj--d3i09HzAhUqyYsBHaNYDlAQ6AF6BAghEAM#v=onepage&q=schwartz%20derive%20lorentz%20transformation%20perturbation%20theory&f=false).

Comment: Anyway, at each stage you introduce 4 parameters ($a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n$) and only have 3 constraints ($x^2,xt,t^2$ coefficients), so resulting in an underdetermined system.  There are ways to fix this, e.g. symmetry, but that is probably not what the question is after.